# Are the any free windows emulators available to test web sites against an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, testing, emulation

I am looking for iPhone emulation software to test a couple of internal web applications against the iPhone.  There are a few quirks occuring with iPhone users that would like to fix but I am unsure how to test them.

For example one of the issues is that numbers are showing up as phone number links on the iPhone which 99% of the time is incorrect.  On regular Windows Safari this doesn't occur.

There are also formatting issues with fonts and spacing that occur on no other broswer except the iPhone version of Safari.

Emulator must be free and work under Windows. Suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't exist. You're better off getting a used Macbook or installing OS X in VirtualBox or something.

Comment: Bear in mind that no emulator is going to do exactly what the real thing will do, and this applies even more to a non-Apple emulator.  Your best bet is to get an iPhone.  If you're maintaining internal web applications, talk to your manager, because you need one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Windows build of WebKit embedded inside an iPhone-like shape called Blackbaud iPhone Browser Simulator. You can download it here http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662

Comment: This won't have the issue with numbers being hyperlinked with call://######### URLs though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for general WebKit issues, Safari 4 and Chrome use fairly similar builds of WebKit. Most issues can be troubleshooted in that manner.

For things like the automated `tel://##########` hyperlinking, though, you're likely SOL. That's an iPhone specific customisation of WebKit. It can be disabled (details in someone else's answer here) but you're not going to be able to test for the behaviour on Windows.

Comment: the tel:// hyperlinking has nothing to do with webkit, and isn't a customisation. The iPhone OS responds to the tel:// url scheme and registers an application that can handle it. In this case, the phone app. Other apps can register their own url schemes too, eg: Twitterific uses one to enable the safari bookmarklet to open Twitterific and pass in some text to tweet (useful before copy and paste was added).

Comment: The OS responds to them, but Webkit (and Mail and a few other apps) automatically detects strings that look like numbers and turn them into `tel://` links. No stock WebKit build is going to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another iphone webkit emulator :

http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/

Build by genuitec, the creators of myEclipse. It's better than using safari desktop as it's a modified version of webkit in order to have the same behavior than safari iPhone. But in reality, it's not 100% equal !